# ejb-example is not working properly when trying to integrate TomEE 1.7.2 with embedded Tomcat

Tags: java, ejb, jndi, openejb, apache-tomee

I'm trying to integrate TomEE 1.7.2 to an embedded tomcat server instance along with  OpenEJB 4.7.2 and OWB 1.2.7. I have created an OSGi bundle which contains them and CXF.

I'm trying to test the TomEE integration using the ejb-example which is provided with TomEE. I tested the JNDI dump by running it on my server and standard TomEE distribution.

In my server it is missing all the openejb stuffs

```
env/openejb=
env/openejb/Resource=
env/openejb/Resource/context.xml=
env/openejb/Resource/context.xml/resource=[ResourceBean ContextResource]
env/openejb/Resource/ejb-examples-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT=
env/openejb/Resource/ejb-examples-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/context.xml=
env/openejb/Resource/ejb-examples-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/context.xml/resource=[ResourceBean ContextResource]
env/openejb/Resource/ejb-examples-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/web.xml=
env/openejb/Resource/ejb-examples-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/web.xml/resource-env-ref=[ResourceBean ContextResourceEnvRef]
env/openejb/Resource/ejb-examples-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/web.xml/resource-ref=[ResourceBean ContextResourceRef]
env/openejb/Resource/web.xml=
env/openejb/Resource/web.xml/resource-env-ref=[ResourceBean ContextResourceEnvRef] 
  env/openejb/Resource/web.xml/resource-ref=[ResourceBean ContextResourceRef]
```

And in the annotated example datasource is null.

What could be the reasons for these issues? 
Is it because may be configurations aren't pick up correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was Resource.class was loaded from 2 bundles. I have 
javax.annotation in my tomcat orbit bundle and inside tomcat-annotation. I 
removed the javax.annotation from tomcat bundle. So now it is working as 
expected :)

you can read upon the TomEE user thread regarding this as @rmannibucau pointed [TomEE Mail thread](http://tomee-openejb.979440.n4.nabble.com/ejb-example-is-not-working-properly-when-trying-to-integrate-TomEE-1-7-2-Integration-with-embedded-Tt-td4675013.html)

Answer (score 1):

Just to not let this thread pending here are the outcomes http://tomee-openejb.979440.n4.nabble.com/ejb-example-is-not-working-properly-when-trying-to-integrate-TomEE-1-7-2-Integration-with-embedded-Tt-td4675013.html

Comment: sorry I forget about this post. I put the answer here. Thanks for reminder